# How to find shortest route along with shortest cost in Floyd-Warshal Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

We know Floyd-Warshal algorithm gives us the shortest cost/path to go any node from anyother node.

For example:

[image]

From above image we can achieve the below matrix as a result of Floyd-Warshal algo as all pair shortest path(cost)

[image]

If you want to go from node 4 to node 3 then there are two ways

- 4 --> 2 --> 3 (cost is 2)
- 4 --> 2 --> 1 --> 3 (cost is 1. So this is shortest route)

From the matrix we are seeing that the value of Row 4 and Column 3 is **1**. So this is showing us the shortest cost between these two nodes.

Now my question is -

**How can I get the route as well (4-->2-->1-->3) ?**

Answer (score 0):

When you have negative edge costs, the trick is to add the absolute value of the smallest cost to every edge ( so that all edges have a zero or positive cost )  In your example, add 2 to every edge cost.

Then the cheapest path can be found in the usual way.

Comment: This is incorrect, counter-example: `G  =  (a,b) : 5,  (b,c) : 2,  (c,a) : -10`, assuming you start from `a`,  you can infinitely cycle to keep reducing distance.

Comment: Your approach also does not work with no negative cycles, counter-example: `G  =  (a,b) : 5,  (b,c) : -10,  (a,c) : 2`, then the cheapest paths from `a` are `(a->b) : 2` and `(a->b->c): -5`. With your method, it states cheapest paths are `(a->b) : 15`, `(a->c) : 12`, which is incorrect for the path `a->c`.

Comment: @idog You need to read my answer more carefully.

Comment: Actually I didn't ask to find smallest cost rather asked how can I find the route of that smallest path ?
Like, A ---> C ---> D

Comment: I am confused.  In your post you number the vertices ( 1,2,3,...)  In your comment you give them letters ( A,C,D ).  Can you clarify please?